# How to change modifier properties of multiple objects at once?

Tags: modifiers

I have many leaves and I have applied a modifier to all of them using `ctrl + L` -> `copy modifiers`.
Although now I would like to change their property at once.

I tried `right click` (on the property) -> `Copy to selected`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the objects
2. `Alt` `Left-Click` the icon